# Modifications and changes to 2011 Specialized BigHit, anyone done these?

Tags: mountain-bike, downhill

I am looking to go from 36 tooth front ring to 32 or smaller.., possibly 30. The 2011 BigHit comes with 36 tooth front ring and medium cage rear derailleur stock.  Has anyone made this change?  Will a change to long cage be necessary for 32 tooth front?

Also looking at putting in a 8.5 Fox air Ava shock for rear to get weight down..  bad idea?  I'm pretty old so a lot of air time is not in my resume but I do like hitting some speed in downhill.

I made the rims tubless with gorilla tape and slime/latex sauce mixture, but I don't think that saved too much weight. The BigHit is 40lbs on the nose now and would like to get it to 36lbs if possible.

Suggestions or remedies you have done would be helpful. Thanks, Henry

Comment: Isn't worrying about weight and owning a Bighit an oxymoron?

Comment: If you want to be lighter, its cheaper to exercise and take the weight off the rider. Taking the same weight off the bike gets real expensive really quickly.

Comment: Open mold CF rims will save you some weight for sure, given that you are open for a 400USD upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Just looking at some pictures of the Specialized Big Hit I believe it’s a single front ring setup.

You can easily swap the ring out for a smaller one down to the minimum supported by the BCD (bolt center diameter) of your crank.

You do not need a different derailleur cage but you may need to shorten the chain.